# Can't rotate screen in Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell Inspiron 7506 2-in-1

Tags: display, dell, inspiron, rotate

I have a problem with my laptop (Dell Inspiron 7506 2n1) with Ubuntu 20.04.
I would like to rotate the screen to use the computer in portait mode. However, nothing happens when I put the screen vertically. Actually, I can't even change the orientation manually: when I go in Settings\Screens, if I change the orientation, nothing changes and the choice box stays on "Landscape".

`xrandr -o left` returns:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  2 (RRSetScreenConfig)
  Serial number of failed request:  14
  Current serial number in output stream:  14
```

`sudo lshw -c display` returns:

```
 *-display NON-RÉCLAMÉ     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Intel Corporation
       fabricant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 01
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration : latency=0
       ressources : mémoireE/S:600-5ff mémoireE/S:400-3ff mémoire:601e000000-601effffff mémoire:4000000000-400fffffff portE/S:3000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff mémoire:4010000000-4016ffffff mémoire:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

My graphics "card" is Intel Iris Xe graphics.

Does anyone know where to start to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The display driver seems to be absent. Run `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel` and retry rotating the screen.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No, it is installed, I just checked.
```xserver-xorg-video-intel est déjà la version la plus récente (2:2.99.917+git20200226-1).```

Comment: xrandr --output <name> --rotate left

<name> is your display name from xrandr output